# How do you view a different branch of your GitHub Pages?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

My master branch is accessible by {USERNAME}.github.io. Let's say I make a new branch named "mobile" and make some new commits on the web interface. How to do I view the new mobile branch, locally, without merging it into master?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub Pages are built on top of [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), which you can also [install and run locally](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#installing-jekyll). The short version is:

1. Install [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/)
2. Install [Bundler](http://bundler.io/)
3. Install the version of Jekyll that GitHub uses by creating a `Gemfile` that contains

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
   gem 'github-pages'
   ```

   and running `bundle install`

Once that is done you can [run Jekyll locally](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#running-jekyll) in a way that matches GitHub's setup for Pages:

> ### Running Jekyll
>
> To run Jekyll in a way that matches the GitHub Pages build server, run Jekyll with Bundler. Use the command `bundle exec jekyll serve` in the root of your repository (after switching to the `gh-pages` branch for project repositories), and your site should be available at `http://localhost:4000`. For a full list of Jekyll commands, see the [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/).

I believe you'll want to do this from your `mobile` branch.

Comment: I'd just like to view the mobile branch for testing purposes before merging it into master, if I do choose to.

Comment: @RogerMortis, sorry for the misunderstanding. I've replaced my answer with a completely new one.

Comment: why is this an accepted answer, i would assume you want to hit the public facing endpoint and not run it locally as your question suggests.

Comment: @AnirudhGoel, look at [the history of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24271298/revisions). I initially answered from the perspective of running on GitHub Pages (you can't use any branch except `master` for user or org pages), but in the comments the OP [clarified that they wanted to test the branch before merging into `master`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271225/how-do-you-view-a-different-branch-of-your-github-pages/24271298?noredirect=1#comment37500337_24271298).

Answer (score 3):

One option might be to fork your primary repo to a secondary one (call it beta.yourdomain.com) and then build there and test on the beta domain, before pull-requesting the final version back into your master repo.

TL;DR - don't use a branch, use a forked repo and a subdomain to preview the build :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to grapple with this too and ended up with the following. My branching strategy is that I release from a release/version-number branch. Once a new release is cut, I merge it to master and create the next release branch based off that. The master branch always contains the latest /docs content, which happens to be javadocs. I then advise the reader that if he wishes to see an older version of the javadoc to clone the repository locally, checkout the branch of interest, and load docs/index.html in the browser.